# java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized, calling method on "onResume"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I will get data from Detail Activity's, so i am updating the Map on "onResume" and it is crashing on animateCamera method. I tried all the solutions available in SO. Please find the code below:

Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized

```
private void zoomToShowAllMarkers(final GoogleMap map) {

        final LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (MapLocations marker : arrMarkers) {
            final LatLng pos = new LatLng(marker.getLatitude(),marker.getLongitude());
             builder.include(pos);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos));

              map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos, 17.0f));

        }
}


public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mapView!=null &&  mapView.isShown())
        mapView.onResume();
        zoomToShowAllMarkers(map);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html,

> Prior to using any methods from this class, you must do one of the
>   following to ensure that this class is initialized:
>
> - Wait for a `GoogleMap` to become available from a `MapFragment` or `MapView` that you have added to your application. You can verify that the `GoogleMap` is available by calling the `getMap()` method and    checking that the returned object is not null.
> - Call `initialize(Context)`. As long as a    `GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException` isn't thrown, this class will 
>     be correctly initialized.

You have to make sure it's initialized before you can call any methods on it.

Comment: I removed GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException catch clause in below code due to error "Unreachable catch block for GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body".

Comment: try {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
   } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put your `zoomToShowAllMarkers(map);` method under `if` statement, cause when you try to animateCamera, your `mapView` probably is `null`, like this:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mapView!=null &&  mapView.isShown()) {
        mapView.onResume();
        zoomToShowAllMarkers(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support @Romadja, the issue is i have a condition for Map Initialization which is not passing during onCreate, so that's the reason for crash. With your comments this bug fixing approach went though deeper. Thanks Romadja.

Answer (score 0):

The device I was testing on had an outdated version of Google Play Services. To avoid the null pointer, I just did a simple check for null. When the user attemps to access the map, they'll get a prompt saying they're out of date.

```
private void setupMap() {
    final GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    MapsInitializer.initialize(this);

    double lat = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lat", 37.6329946);
    double lng = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lng", -122.4938344);
    float zoom = getIntent().getFloatExtra("zoom", 15);

    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    if(null != map) {
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, zoom));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position));

        map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                map.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        mapLoaded(bitmap);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```